# Term for Gift that Turns out to be a Burden

Tags: single-word-requests, phrase-requests, american-english, idiom-requests

What is the English term for when someone thinks they are doing something nice for you but it ends up making things worse. EX: Someone buys you an elephant -- nice gesture and cool! But now you have to take care of it, and it becomes a burden on you.

Comment: Not too gift-specific but "albatross" comes to mind.

Comment: I thought about "Danaian gift", but it seems, that only non-native speakers use that in their texts, because it exist in their native languages (like Danaergeshenk). It comes from https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Timeo_Danaos_et_dona_ferentes

Answer (score 86):

In fact, the English expression for a burdensome gift is literally *[white elephant](http://www.oxfordlearnersdictionaries.com/us/definition/english/white-elephant)*:

> a thing that is useless and no longer needed, although it may have cost a lot of money [OALD]

So-called white elephants, or albino elephants, are found in many parts of South and Southeast Asia. In Buddhist countries they may be venerated as Queen Maya, mother of the Buddha, was said to have been visited in a dream by a white elephant holding a white lotus flower, and Siddharth Gautama entered his mother's womb in the form a white elephant. The white elephant is also associated with traits like mental strength and purity.

It became a royal symbol in Siam (Thailand); the king continues to [keep  white elephants](http://www.thailandelephant.org/). The story emerged that if a courtier displeased him, the king would make him a gift of a white elephant. The courtier could hardly decline a royal gift, and could hardly afford not to maintain a sacred animal, and could not put it to productive use, and so would be ruined by the cost of upkeep.

The earliest example of its use is from a 1721 essay in *London Journal*:

> In short, Honour and Victory are generally no more than white Elephants; and for white Elephants the most destructive Wars have been often made.

A 2011 paper by Ross Bullen entitled [“This Alarming Generosity”: White Elephants and the Logic of the Gift](http://americanliterature.dukejournals.org/content/83/4/747.abstract), in *American Literature*, covers the popularization of the term in the mid-19th century, presents an alternative account, that the story is a piece of orientalism and the white elephant rose as a literary trope.

Comment: No it isn't. That is failed, expensive project, usually infrastructure and often accompanied by corruption and cronyism.

Comment: @aaa90210 Please cite literally any usage of "white elephant" in that context.

Comment: @aaa90210: You're correct that "white elephant" is currently used for failed projects.  Following the etymological origins, the story of the king who gives white elephants, "white elephant" fits the OP's "gift that turns out to be a burden" to a tee. And it fits with a failed project for the same reason: You initially thought the project was going to benefit you, but after you're committed you realize that it's going to cost you.

Comment: A white elephant describes something that was a waste and implies purchasing it was a mistake, but not necessarily that the thing is a burden.

Comment: Currant usage I have heard and used is in relation to a *white elephant party*, where attendees are to bring a gift.  These gifts are generally low cost and chosen for comedic or mortifying effect, as well as a general uselessness.  This usage is directly descended from the gifting of White Elephants.    https://www.whiteelephantrules.com/

Comment: @aaa90210 I think the word you are thinking of is "boondoggle"; at least I've never heard "white elephant" used to mean that.

Comment: @JeremyFriesner jeez, lets do google search and see what we come up with: https://www.google.com/search?q=white+elephant&source=lnms&tbm=nws&biw=1920&bih=949

Comment: Even if this answer were correct, it's still not _literally_ a white elephant, unless someone has given you an actual elephant that is white in color.

Comment: The divergence from the original meaning described here, to the definition given by @aaa90210 appears to be British. American English would use "boondoggle" instead.

Comment: @erickson - as far as my understanding of "boondoggle" goes, which isn't commonly used in Britain, there's a difference in purpose: AIUI a boondoggle is an expensive project deliberately chosen to give economic advantage to a certain group of people, whereas a white elephant is a project that was *probably* originally begun with good intentions, but due to bureaucracy, corruption, incompetence (or all 3) has become overly expensive and/or unfit for purpose....

Comment: E.g. the [now scrapped NHS medical record centralization project](http://www.telegraph.co.uk/science/2016/07/06/controversial-50-million-nhs-database-scrapped-quietly-on-same-d/) was a *white elephant*, but I would never have described it as a *boondoggle* due to the fact that it was (as far as I can see) *begun in good faith* with an intent only to *reduce operating costs and improve services by reducing waste caused by duplicated effort*.

Comment: I've always used this term as a metaphor for some mythical special creature that people might go to right to go great effort and expense to hunt down as a trophy, but as yet has never been caught. Hence NHS example from @Jules is a good example, since many people have identified such a project as a good idea and have tried to implement it, but it's always cost too much and never been achieved.

Comment: @eyeballfrog That's the standard usage around here (Australia). Example: http://www.abc.net.au/news/2017-07-12/state-government-reopens-warburton-work-camp-prison/8701576 http://www.afr.com/news/economy/pc-issues-white-elephant-warning-for-snowy-20-musk-battery-20170728-gxkrpp  http://www.canberratimes.com.au/national/public-service/government-abandons-210-million-shared-services-white-elephant-20170524-gwc0u6.html http://www.theaustralian.com.au/business/opinion/david-uren-economics/malcolm-turnbull-in-muddle-as-snowy-river-scheme-to-lift-debt/news-story/7449ebc0bf078579e312b47e550f5472

Comment: @Jules, In America we might still call that a boondoggle, if the reason it failed is because it was managed to deliver economic advantage to the workers or contractors working on it, rather than to achieve its original objectives.

Comment: Never heard white elephant used this way.

Comment: If I heard the phrase used this way I'd be confused and think you meant a white elephant gift party (I've never heard it used this way actually). Probably a regional thing

Comment: Note that, per the description of the origin of the term, the giving of a white elephant was *not* something the giver thought of as being nice to do for the recipient, but rather something that would explicitly ruin them.

Comment: Current usage of "white elephant" gives only the sense that the thing is redundant, and not that it was a well-intentioned gift.

Comment: This has always been my understanding of the original meaning of the phrase (in the US). Both "white elephant sales" and "white elephant parties" are common around me, and the common element is that they are a way of getting rid of items that are useless to you but that you can't bring yourself to throw away, often because they were gifts.

Comment: Just a curiosity as it is a bit off topic here. In current Portuguese we also use these terms with meanings similar to described here. White Elephant (Elefante Branco) for expensive projects with not a lot of function and "Poisoned Gift" (Presente Envenenado) with a meaning similar to Poisoned Chalice as described in another answer here.

Comment: @Monty Harder: the gift itself is not literally a white elephant, but the expression describing such a gift *is* literally "white elephant".

Answer (score 34):

> **Poisoned Chalice**

This is perhaps darker than the question envisages, but I add it for its literary pedigree*. [The Cambridge Advanced Learner’s Dictionary & Thesaurus](http://dictionary.cambridge.org/dictionary/english/poisoned-chalice) explains it as:

> “Something that seems very good when it is first received, but in fact
>   does great harm to the person who receives it”

–————————————————————————————————————————————————

*According to [Oxford Reference](http://www.oxfordreference.com/view/10.1093/oi/authority.20110803100333715):

> An assignment, award, or honour which is likely to prove a
>   disadvantage or source of problems to the recipient; the phrase is
>   found originally in Shakespeare’s Macbeth (1606), in a speech in which
>   Macbeth flinches from the prospective murder of Duncan.

Comment: Hate to downvote this, but the question is clearly about a situation where the donor "thinks they are doing something nice for you". A poison chalice is administered with intent.

Comment: @DominicCronin — Not necessarily. It can just be 'there' for the taking rather than administered, although in that case I agree it's not a gift, and one does talk about accepting a poison chalice. However the modern meaning of white elephant doesn't imply cost, just uselessness. It's not always possible to find an exact fit.

Comment: People don't just leave poisoned chalices lying around.

Comment: @DominicCronin — No, but you could regard a high political office as something that is 'there' to be grasped if others are hesitant, but may turn out to be a poisoned challice. btw No hard feelings about the downvote, especially as you explained why.

Answer (score 10):

"White elephant" refers to a gift that's a burden, but the origins came from a situation where the burden was intentional. Albatross, money pit, and millstone all refer to burdens, but not specifically gifts.

Comment: Hello, Accumulation. This is a comment on another answer, not a separate answer.

Comment: @edwinashworth I don't think it's a comment. One answer mentions white elephant as well, but this answer provides more examples, and doesn't directly reference the other answer. It is very short though, and could stand to be expanded

Answer (score 7):

> a gift that keeps on giving

An ironic expression that indicates the "gift" has some ongoing and undesired consequences.

Comment: "Stop little cooking pot, stop!" :)

Comment: Worth pointing out that this is sometimes used without the sarcasm too, so might not work too well in written contexts.

Comment: I've actually never heard a real life use of the phrase that was sarcastic. I HAVE read passeges that seem to imply sarcasm, but as muzer said, it was a bit hard to tell.

Comment: Strange, I have never seen it used *not* sarcastic.

Comment: @Muzer It was even [trademarked](http://quotes.yourdictionary.com/articles/what-commercial-said-the-gift-that-keeps-on-giving.html)
in 1927 by the [Victor Talking Machine Company for phonographs](http://answers.google.com/answers/threadview?id=124814).

Comment: This is not in and of itself an ironic expression. It was originally and is presumably still used literally. There is definitely an additional ironic *sense* or *usage* though.

Comment: @Wossname The book we have that in uses "Stop, pot, stop", but as the original story is not in English (German maybe?), you translation is probably more literal.  I've also seen a story from India with monkeys, but I don't remember the required phrase.

Comment: @GuySchalnat, quite probably, yes.  Most of the inane drivel that we 80's kids (in the UK) were forced to ingest was heavily re-worked in order to compete with cartoons on the TV at the time.  This usually meant that cultural authenticity was the first casualty.  It's a small miracle that I remember this at all :)

Answer (score 6):

Perhaps a stretch, but I offer **Pandora's Box**:

> [a source of extensive but unforeseen troubles or problems](http://www.dictionary.com/browse/pandora-s-box)

Answer (score 1):

***Zonk*** was popularized by the U.S. television game show *Let's Make a Deal*.  From the [Wikipedia article](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Let%27s_Make_a_Deal):

> The [show's] format ... [traders] make deals with the host. In most cases, a trader will be offered something of value and given a choice of whether to keep it or exchange it for a different item. The program's defining game mechanism is that the other item is hidden from the trader until that choice is made. The trader thus does not know if he or she is getting something of greater value or a prize that is referred to as a **"zonk," an item purposely chosen to be of little or no value** to the trader.

Emphasis is mine.   Any connoisseur of U.S. television game shows will know this.

Alas, upon consulting with [Merriam-Webster](https://www.merriam-webster.com/dictionary/zonk) and [Dictionary.com](http://www.dictionary.com/browse/zonk), *zonk* does not appear with this meaning.  Oddly, both dictionaries define it only as a verb.   ...  Didn't they ever watch television?

Comment: The asker specifies the giver must believe they're giving a valuable gift, and that its true lack of value or harmfulness is only apparent to the one receiving it. Even if a "zonk" has a chance of being valuable, it doesn't fit the specific need in the question. In fact if you were to describe someone's worthless gift as a "zonk" you'd be implying that they knew it was worthless when they gave it.

Comment: @talrnu:  One aspect I didn't mention is that sometimes the gifts which are *meant* to be worthless or a burden are actually welcome.  Like the period of time which the zonk door had a live llama behind it.  Some contestants had farms and welcomed receiving this animal.

Comment: Interestingly, [this answer on a related question](https://movies.stackexchange.com/a/17789/53698) elaborates that the intent was never for the contestant to actually take the zonk home (though it was their legal right to), the few times it actually happened costing the show a small fortune.